# преобразование типа String в пользовательский тип С++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы, типы, преобразование-типов

Необходимо перегрузить оператор присваивания = , чтобы присваивать объектам класса значения типа `string`, в этом новичок, почитал на msdn, как это делать, но при перегрузке оператора вылетает ошибка (в коде указал строчку комментарием) "Ошибка C2440 return: невозможно преобразовать "std::string" в "parametres" " и ошибка " не существует подходящего определяемого пользователем преобразования из "std::string" в "parametres" ", прошу помочь найти решение :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class parametres :string {

public:
    operator string() {
        getStr();
}

parametres& operator=(string &other) {
//  parametres p;
    str_par = other;
    return *this;
}

string getStr() {
    return str_par;
}

private:
    string str_par;
    int int_par;
    char ch_par;
};


void print(parametres par) {
    string s = par.getStr();
    cout << s;
    cout << "works...";
}


int main()
{

parametres p;
string s;
s = "thisisstring";
p = s;
print(p);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: operator= должен возвращать референс на *this а принимать стоит const & lhs,поскольку аргумент изменять не должен

Comment: добавил return *this; и в параметр принимаемый добавил const , все также p принимает значение p="";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете временную переменную внутри оператора и изменяете ее. А надо изменять мембер класса

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class parametres  {
public:
    operator std::string() const {
        getStr();
    }

    parametres& operator=(const std::string &other) {
        str_par = other;
        return *this;    //тут ошибка
    }

    std::string getStr() const {
        return str_par;
    }

private:
    std::string str_par;
    int int_par;
    char ch_par;
};


void print(parametres par) {
    std::string s = par.getStr();
    std::cout << s;
}


int main()
{
    parametres p;
    std::string s;
    s = "thisisstring";
    p = s;
    print(p);
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, понял, глупая ошибка, почувствовал себя идиотом чуть чуть :)

Answer (score 2):

Так надо перегружать

```
parametres& operator=(string &other) { 
str_par = other; return *this; //тут ошибка 
}
```

Comment: ошибки действительно не выдает, но теперь просто не выводится ничего

Comment: В определении оператора значок & поставить
parametres& operator=

Comment: Для операторов присваивания необходимо возвращать ссылку на измененный элемент.

Comment: поставил, все еще ничего не изменило это

Comment: А если поставить точку останова на print и посмотреть, что внутри p?

Comment: то можно увидеть пустое значение p = ""

Comment: все работает, спасибо, понял :) можно удалять комментарии, перенесу все в код здесь сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Создается `parametres p;`, то есть должен вызываться конструктор класса без параметров. А где он? Там должен инициализироваться `string`, ведь для него память нужна. Совершенно непонятно, каково значение стринга по умолчанию. И через параметр задать его нельзя. Попробуйте создать конструктор. Ведь `string` сложный класс сам по себе.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как и зачем string в конструкторе инициализировать